# Laravel and Local Tunnel integration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localtunnel

My idea was to use Local Tunnel's subdomain feature to expose callback URI in a more convenient way. However, I believe that I could've achieved the same results in a simper way.

This is the solution with Laravel Valet:

In **package.json** I've added a script called `shared`

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "share": "lt --port 80 --subdomain blog --local-host blog.test"
}
```

In **AppServiceProvider.php** I've extended the `UrlGenerator` to avoid redirecting back to `http://blog.test`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\LocalTunnelUrlGenerator;
use Blade;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        (...)
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->enableLocalTunnel();
    }

    private function enableLocalTunnel()
    {
        if (!app()->environment('local') || !config('app.use_local_tunnel')) {
            return;
        }

        $this->app->extend('url', function (UrlGenerator $defaultGenerator) {
            /** @var Router $router */
            $router = $this->app['router'];
            $routes = $router->getRoutes();

            return new LocalTunnelUrlGenerator($routes, $defaultGenerator->getRequest());
        });
    }
}
```

This is the the **LocalTunnelUrlGenerator.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class LocalTunnelUrlGenerator extends UrlGenerator
{
    public function __construct(RouteCollection $routes, Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct($routes, $request);
    }

    public function formatRoot($scheme, $root = null)
    {
        return "https://blog.localtunnel.me";
    }
}
```

Why all that? Because whenever the application call the `redirect()` method, we are sent back to http://blog.test.

[image: where the problem happens]

Do I really need to extend the `UrlGenerator` to make it work?

Comment: I don't have enough context to understand the question. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish in terms of cURL, or otherwise showing the list of request-response events that you expect to have happen?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Why are you using `blog.test` at all?

Comment: My valet is using `.test` domain and `blog` is just a sample project.

Comment: Why not use the localtunnel domain for the whole stack though?

Comment: Out of the box, we get redirected to the local domain by the default implementation of the `getHost` method.